# React component not receiving props on Redux store update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

I am building a social media application using the MERN stack and Redux as the state manager. I have a feed component which renders PostItem components which display the post and allow for actions such as liking, and commenting. I also have a Post component that renders the same PostItem component that opens when the user clicks the comment button on the PostItem component in the feed. When I like a post via the feed component it receives the updated props and rerenders the component showing the changes. However when I click the like button in the Post component it updates the Redux store but does not receive the updated props.

Feed.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPosts } from '../../actions/post';

// Components
import UserProfileCard from './UserProfileCard';
import PostForm from './PostForm';
import Footer from '../layout/Footer';
import PostItem from '../posts/PostItem';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';

const Feed = ({ getPosts, post: { posts, loading } }) => {
  //Same as component did mount
  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, [getPosts]);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='main-container mt-3'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='row'>
            <UserProfileCard />
            <PostForm />
          </div>
          {loading ? (
            <Spinner />
          ) : (
            posts.map(post => <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />)
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Feed.propTypes = {
  getPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts })(Feed);
```

Post.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPost } from '../../actions/post';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
import PostCommentForm from './PostCommentForm';
import Comment from './Comment';

// Assets
import { ArrowLeft } from 'react-feather';

const Post = ({ getPost, post: { post, loading }, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // get id from url in params for getPost function
    getPost(match.params.id);
  }, [getPost]);
  return loading || post === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <div className='main-container mt-3'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
          {/* TODO ADD BROWSER HISTORY FUNCTIONALITY TO ALLOW USER TO GO BACK TO PROFILE OR FEED */}
          <Link className='mb-1' to='/feed'>
            <button className='btn btn-logo-color'>
              <ArrowLeft />
            </button>
          </Link>
          <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />
          <PostCommentForm />
        </div>
        <Comment />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Post.propTypes = {
  getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPost })(Post);
```

PostItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addLike, removeLike, deletePost } from '../../actions/post';

// Assets
import { ThumbsUp, ThumbsDown, MessageSquare, XCircle } from 'react-feather';
import avi from '../assets/default-avatar.png';

const PostItem = ({
  auth,
  post: { _id, text, firstname, lastname, user, likes, comments, date },
  addLike,
  removeLike,
  deletePost
}) => {
  return (
    <div className='card mt-1 post'>
      <div className='card-body'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-lg-2'>
            <Link className='feed-link' to={`/profile/${user}`}>
              <img src={avi} alt='avatar' className='avatar' />
              <h5 className='card-title mt-2'>
                {firstname} {lastname}
              </h5>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className='col-lg-10'>
            <p className='card-text'>{text}</p>
            <p className='text-muted post-date'>
              <Moment format='LLL'>{date}</Moment>
            </p>

            <div className='post-buttons'>
              <button
                type='button'
                className='btn btn-outline-primary mr-1'
                onClick={e => addLike(_id)}
              >
                <ThumbsUp />
                <span className='badge badge-light'>
                  {likes.length > 0 && <span>{likes.length}</span>}
                </span>
              </button>
              <button
                type='button'
                className='btn btn-outline-danger mr-1'
                onClick={e => removeLike(_id)}
              >
                <ThumbsDown />
              </button>
              {/* TODO ADD CONDITIONAL RENDERING TO REMOVE WHEN POST IS OPEN */}

              <Link to={`/post/${_id}`}>
                <button type='button' className='btn btn-outline-info mr-1'>
                  <MessageSquare />
                  <span className='badge badge-light'>
                    {comments.length > 0 && (
                      <span className='comment-count'>{comments.length}</span>
                    )}
                  </span>
                </button>
              </Link>
              {!auth.loading && user === auth.user._id && (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='btn btn-outline-danger mr-1'
                  onClick={() => deletePost(_id)}
                >
                  <XCircle />
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

PostItem.propTypes = {
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  addLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deletePost: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addLike, removeLike, deletePost })(
  PostItem
);
```

Post Reducer

```
import {
  GET_POSTS,
  POST_ERROR,
  UPDATE_LIKES,
  DELETE_POST,
  ADD_POST,
  GET_POST,
  ADD_COMMENT,
  REMOVE_COMMENT
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  post: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case ADD_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [payload, ...state.posts],
        loading: false
      };
    case DELETE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.filter(post => post._id !== payload),
        loading: false
      };
    case POST_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case UPDATE_LIKES:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post =>
          post._id === payload.postId ? { ...post, likes: payload.likes } : post
        ),
        loading: false
      };
    case ADD_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: { ...state.post, comments: payload },
        loading: false
      };
    case REMOVE_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: {
          ...state.post,
          comments: state.post.comments.filter(
            comment => comment._id !== payload
          )
        },
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state
      };
  }
}
```

Post actions

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';
import {
  GET_POSTS,
  POST_ERROR,
  UPDATE_LIKES,
  DELETE_POST,
  ADD_POST,
  GET_POST,
  ADD_COMMENT,
  REMOVE_COMMENT
} from './types';

//Get posts

export const getPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/posts');

    dispatch({
      type: GET_POSTS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Add like
export const addLike = postId => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/posts/like/${postId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LIKES,
      payload: { postId, likes: res.data }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Remove like
export const removeLike = postId => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/posts/unlike/${postId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LIKES,
      payload: { postId, likes: res.data }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Add Post
export const addPost = formData => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/posts', formData, config);

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Post Created', 'success'));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Delete Post
export const deletePost = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.delete(`/api/posts/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_POST,
      payload: id
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Post Removed', 'success'));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};

//Get post
export const getPost = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/posts/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Add Comment
export const addComment = (postId, formData) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `/api/posts/comment/${postId}`,
      formData,
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_COMMENT,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Comment Added', 'success'));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Delete Comment
export const deleteComment = (postId, commentId) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.delete(`/api/posts/comment/${postId}/${commentId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: REMOVE_COMMENT,
      payload: commentId
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Comment Removed', 'success'));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the `posts` array here which is what you use to render the `PostItems` in `Feed`.

```
case UPDATE_LIKES:
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: state.posts.map(post =>
      post._id === payload.postId ? { ...post, likes: payload.likes } : post
    ),
    loading: false
  };
```

However in `Post.js` you use the `Post` object, not the `Posts` array. `Post` has not been updated by the `UPDATE_LIKES` action so your component doesn't re-render.

Comment: Any tips on how I should go about rendering from the posts array in the Post component?

Comment: Probably store the id of the post the user has selected to comment on, get that post by that id from the posts array in Post.js. Something along those lines should work fine.